# Need to learn recurrence relation discrete mathematics

Tags: engineering-mathematics, discrete-math, computer-science, recursion

Which is the best tutorial available online to learn the recurrence relation concept and its solution in discrete mathematics, in a systematic way?

Answer (score 3):

I liked this [Discrete Mathematics: An Open Introduction](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_recurrence.html), by Oscar Levin, for generating functions, so I'm guessing it will be good for recurrence relations.

Comment: I use this text when I teach discrete math.  It does do a good job of explaining recurrence relations, including a complete derivation of solutions to second order linear recurrence relations.  Not sure why someone would downvote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, I very much liked [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf) by Herbert Wilf; it is the go-to text for what you are seeking.  It addresses generating functions, and considerable help for understanding recurrence relations. (And it's free from the author, and downloadable as a pdf.!)

In addition, you'll find extensive information at Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth, and Oren Patashnik's [Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf).

For beginner information, there are a number of sources and tutorials online.   For example, see [Brilliant.org, recurrence relations](https://brilliant.org/discrete-mathematics/?subtopic=recurrence-relations).

Another potential online source for introductory material is located [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/discrete_mathematics_recurrence_relation.htm).